# how to get a table data where should be checked in another table without joining using linq include or another way?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5.2

i want to get the data of tables where is included in another table but is filtered by a column id that has another realtion with another table

in below i wrote the details

*products* table(only needable columns written)

```
 public partial class Products
{  
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product_Attribut> Product_Attribut { get; set; }
}
```

*Attribute_Item* table

```
public partial class AttributItem
    {  
        public int AttributeID { get; set; }
        public int AttrGrpID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<Product_Attribut> Product_Attribut { get;set; }
}
```

*Product_Attribut* table

```
public partial class Product_Attribut
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProductID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AttributeID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> isChecked { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual AttributItem AttributItem { get; set; }
    public virtual Products Products { get; set; }
}
```

tables are *products* , *Attribute_Item* , *Product_Attribut* that *Product_Attribut* has 1:m relation with these two table which means two 1:m relation

now i want to get *products* data table where in *Product_Atrribute* there should be a row with *productID* and *AttributeID* where *AttributeID* is filtered by a filter ID

```
products = products.Include(pr => pr.Product_Attribut.Select(x => x.AttributeID == Convert.ToInt32(eachfilt[1])));
```

I used this code but i know that is wrong and get the error but don't know how to reach it ? do i need joining two tables or theres another simple way just using Linq?

sample

```
product rows                    
product_id          
1                      
2                      
3                      
4
5

AttributItem rows
attribute_id 
11
12
13
```

now in Product_Attribut tables have this rows

```
product_id     attribute_id
1              11
2              11
2              12
3              12
```

when i set the attribute_id filter to 11  i want the output be the product table with just product 1 and 2 not (3,4 and 5)

Comment: can you please  add question with some sample data and what output you want

Comment: @GaganBurde i wrote the sample and output at the end of question

Comment: posted answer check below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the way you get the data of a table and make filter on another table with one to many relation to this table and the result and output is just the product table and data as what you want to get

```
 var products = db.Products.Include(p => p.Product_Groups);

 products = products.Include(p => p.Product_Attribut).Where(x => x.Product_Attribut.Any(p => p.AttributeID == filter));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: thank you @clijsters to cleared me but this is my answser to my own question and 
 the suggestion is clear to get the output as it mentioned anyway now i added some descripting to answer as you said

Answer (score 0):

You can check below code to get this thing.
You have one to many relationship so from Product_Attribut property we can filter data with the help of linq where clause and then select what user want using annonymous function or the class present in your example.

```
Products product = new Products();
        Product_Attribut attribute = new Product_Attribut();
        attribute.ProductID = 1;
        attribute.AttributeID = 11;


        Product_Attribut attribute1 = new Product_Attribut();
        attribute1.ProductID = 2;
        attribute1.AttributeID = 11;

        Product_Attribut attribute2 = new Product_Attribut();
        attribute2.ProductID = 2;
        attribute2.AttributeID = 12;

        Product_Attribut attribute3 = new Product_Attribut();
        attribute3.ProductID = 3;
        attribute3.AttributeID = 12;

        Product_Attribut attribute4 = new Product_Attribut();
        attribute4.ProductID = 4;
        attribute4.AttributeID = 14;

        product.Product_Attribut = new List<Product_Attribut>();
        product.Product_Attribut.Add(attribute);
        product.Product_Attribut.Add(attribute1);
        product.Product_Attribut.Add(attribute2);
        product.Product_Attribut.Add(attribute3);
        product.Product_Attribut.Add(attribute4);

        var filter = product.Product_Attribut.Where(x => x.AttributeID == 11).Select(x => new Product_Attribut
        {
            ProductID = x.ProductID,
            AttributeID = x.AttributeID
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: but the question remains the output that should be in product table to send it to view in mvc but its in type of Product_Attribute and also I did this var products = db.Products.Include(p => p.Product_Groups); and now i want to put filter on this not in a new Product instance

Comment: hey hey thank u i just found the answer and its in below ,and its the way you get the data of a table and make filter on another table with one to many relation if could be usable for anybody else

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.